# Provide an example where absolute and norm are different

Tags: real-analysis

Is there any difference between absolute and norm? Kindly give an example too that shows the difference, thanks.

Comment: For example, $\Vert x\Vert =2|x|$ defines a norm on $\Bbb R$.

Comment: dear david , kindly explain your answer a little bit . i am still at a loss.

Answer (score 1):

A [norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29) $\|\cdot\|$ defined on a [vector space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) $M$ is a function $M\rightarrow\mathbb R^{+}_0$ having the properties:

- $\|x\|=0\Rightarrow x=0$
- $\|\lambda \cdot x\|=|\lambda| \cdot \|x\|$
- $\|a+b\| \le \|a\|+\|b\|$

The [absolute value function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_value) $|\cdot|:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^{+}_0$ is an example for a norm on the one dimensional vector space $\mathbb R$. There are also other examples for norms on $\mathbb R$, for example $$\|\cdot\|^\prime:\mathbb R\rightarrow \mathbb R^{+}_0:x\mapsto \|x\|^\prime=2\cdot |x|$$ So the absolute value function on $\mathbb R$ (and also on $\mathbb C$) is a norm, but there are also other examples of norms, which are not the absolute value function.

Comment: nice explanation tampis...so what i gather from your explanation is (1)-the functions differ with respect to element i.e the element in abs function is a number(real or complex) whereas the element in norm is a vector [correct me,if i am wrong] . (2)-the functions differ in their geometrical interpretation . abs ftn shows distance between number and origin whereas norm shows length of arrow representing the vector . (3)- abs ftn is defined for only R and C. there is no abs ftn in case of R*R ,R*R*R .but we do have norm in all  above mentioned cases .guide me guys!

Comment: (1): each number is also a vector, so yes and no. (2) thats wrong. each norm defines a different distance. better to say: the absolute value is the euclidean distance between 0 and the element (so the absolute value is the euclidean norm on $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$). (3) yes, I am not aware of a norm which is called absolute value for other domains than $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Maybe there is a absolute value for quaterions but I am not sure...